# Berkeley DB JE environment locks

Tags: berkeley-db-je

I got a problem with berkeley environment. An application can write and read from the environment but when another application tries to retrieve from it,it cannot open the environment because it is locked. I have configured the retrieval process as read only. Any idea why is this so? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure setReadOnly(true) is called on both the StoreConfig and the EnvironmentConfig.